# Inconsitent behaviour of "Sticky" in Tkinter Grid packer

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid

I am working on a small utilty. 
I had problems with tk pack system and i changed whole system to tkinter grid packer. But I can not easily place the widgets wherever i want. Sticky values not applying or applying in an unexpected way. Or I am doing something wrong .

What is wrong with the code below ?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar()
root.minsize(width=400, height=400)

root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
root.grid_propagate(0)

frame = tk.Frame(root,width=400, height=400, bg="cyan")
frame.grid()
frame.grid_propagate(0)

frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

frame1 = tk.Frame(frame,width=200, height=100, bg="green")
frame2 = tk.Frame(frame,width=200, height=100, bg="blue")
frame3 = tk.Frame(frame,width=200, height=100, bg="yellow")
frame4 = tk.Frame(frame,width=200, height=100, bg="grey")
frame1.grid_propagate(0)
frame2.grid_propagate(0)
frame3.grid_propagate(0)
frame4.grid_propagate(0)

tk.Radiobutton(frame1 ,text="TEXT" ,variable=var ,value=1,indicatoron=0
    ,width=16 , height=1 ).grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(frame2 ,text="TEXT" ,variable=var ,value=2,indicatoron=0
    ,width=16 , height=1 ).grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(frame3 ,text="TEXT" ,variable=var ,value=3,indicatoron=0
    ,width=16 , height=1 ).grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(frame4 ,text="TEXT" ,variable=var ,value=4,indicatoron=0
    ,width=16 , height=1 ).grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W)

frame1.grid(row=0,column=0)
frame2.grid(row=0,column=1)
frame3.grid(row=1,column=0)
frame4.grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is how it looks.
[image]

I expect these buttons/radio buttons stretch to the limits of the frame they were placed in cause i use

```
grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W) .
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You've correctly given a weight to the rows and columns in `frame`, but you've not applied weights anywhere else. When you place a radiobutton in `frame1`, it is smaller than that frame. It is "sticking" to the edges of column zero, but column zero hasn't been configured to take up all the space in `frame1`.

Add this one line to observe the difference it makes:

```
frame1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: But what s the point to give weights on the widgets that i have given in the layout grid already .? Isn't this impractical ?

Comment: That is really working .. I guess i am having problems with understanding the logic  ..Thank you  Bryan...

Comment: @user7685914: Every widget that contains other widgets using `grid` uses a completely different grid configuration. The weights given to a parent does not affect the rows of columns of widgets nested inside. A rule of thumb is that for _every_ frame or window that uses grid to manage its immediate children, you should give a non-zero weight to at least one row and one column.